# Session variables not being detected when submitting forms

Tags: php, forms, session

So I've ran into a weird problem that's occurring sometimes when I submit forms.  Occasionally after a form is submitted some session objects stop being detected on next page.

I include this at the top off all my pages for the login \ timeout security and it seems to be to problem (as when I remove it everything works fine)  but I can't for the life of me figure out what the heck is going on.  It's especially weird because it doesn't log me out, but session variables like group_id which I store when you log in stop working.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["CREATED"]))  {
    if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1800)) {
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        $link = "https://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . "/";
        header('Location: ' . $link, true, 301);
    } else {
        $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();
    }
} else {
        $link = "https://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . "/";
        header('Location: ' . $link, true, 301);    
}
```

Comment: What is your session timeout value? What about the session cookie expiration?

Comment: When this condition is true: (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1800)) you are destroying your session.

Comment: (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1800)) is intended to destroy the session if they haven't had any activity for 30 minutes or more, the issue is occurring even if someone logs in and goes directly to the form.

Session \ cookie timesouts are set at 3600 for default ATM I believe.